# How to cache listview Images in windows phone 8.1 xaml based Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, caching, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone 8.1 c# album application where user can view their album and some information . when I clicked from user's list album page will display all images , on click on Image I have to navigate on another page for some extra work , but the problem is when I navigate from another page to album page all data are fetch from api , but I wanted them into cache . 
I tried following code on album page constructor

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

it will cache but when I click on different user album give me cache album .
please help me for that 
here is my gridview

```
   <GridView x:Name="grdRecentMedia" CacheMode="BitmapCache" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="grdRecentMedia_SelectionChanged"   ContainerContentChanging="grdRecentMedia_ContainerContentChanging"  >
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid MaxHeight="122" Width="122" Margin="2" CacheMode="BitmapCache" >
                                    <Image CacheMode="BitmapCache"  x:Name="imgRecentMedia"  Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding images.thumbnail.url}" />
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="elpVidio" Fill="Blue" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
```

Comment: Neither NavigationCacheMode nor CacheMode have anything to do with caching of bitmaps. This is however already done by Windows Runtime when you use Uris for the Image.Source property. An alternative would be to create the bitmaps in your view model and have a property of type ImageSource instead of Uri.

Comment: Can't you just make the data 'static'?